# Automate SSH Configuration for new Hadoop cluster

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop, ssh, sshpass

Guessing this has been done many times, but I could not find a clean answer, so I am appealing to your expertise for a better solution:

**Objective:**  I am setting up a moderate sized RHEL Hadoop cluster and want to automate the configuration of SSH connectivity between all nodes.  On the first node I have a list of all of the IPs in the file 'remote_ips', and I have the hduser password in the file 'hduser_pw' (chmod 600).

Step 1) Create "hduser_pw" password file on each host

`for x in $(cat remote_ips); do sshpass -p$(cat hduser_pw) ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@$x "echo $(cat hduser_pw) > hduser_pw; chmod 600 hduser_pw"; done`

Step 2) Generate RSA keys for each node in cluster:

`for x in $(cat remote_ips); do sshpass -p$(cat hduser_pw) ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@$x "echo -e  'y'| ssh-keygen -t rsa -N \"\"
 "; done`

Step 3) Copy the file 'remote_ips' to each node in the cluster:

`for x in $(cat remote_ips); do sshpass -p$(cat hduser_pw) scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no remote_ips hduser@$x:~; done`

Step 4) For each node, copy the RSA public key to "authorized_keys" in every other node:

`for x in $(cat remote_ips); do sshpass -p$(cat hduser_pw) ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@$x 'for y in $(cat remote_ips); do cat /home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | sshpass -p$(cat hduser_pw) ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@$y '\''cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'\'' ; done '; done`

Is there a better way to do this?  Really appreciate your help.

## EDIT:  Here are my revisions:

I incorporated the feedback from @janos and @likewhoa --> I handled the UUOC with redirection, looped across each IP, removed any pwds from the shell history with variables, etc.  Thanks so much!

```
hduser_pw=$(< hduser_pw)
remote_ips=$(< remote_ips)

for x in $remote_ips; do
    echo "Create hduser_pw password file on node: ${x}"
    sshpass -p$hduser_pw scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser_pw hduser@$x:~

    echo "chmod 600 hduser_pw on node: ${x}"
    sshpass -p$hduser_pw ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@$x "chmod 600 hduser_pw"

    echo "Generate RSA keys for: ${x}"
    sshpass -p$hduser_pw ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@$x "echo y | ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -N \"\""

    echo "SCP the file remote_ips to node: ${x}"
    sshpass -p$hduser_pw scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no remote_ips hduser@$x:~
done

for x in $remote_ips; do 
    for y in $remote_ips; do
        echo "ssh-copy-id from node ${x} to node ${y}:"
        sshpass -p$hduser_pw ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@$x "sshpass -p${hduser_pw} ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hduser@${y} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no";
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running `$(cat hduser_pw)` and `$(cat remote_ips)` multiple times,
it would be better to run them only once and, save in variables and reuse.
For example:

```
hduser_pw=$(cat hduser_pw)
remote_ips=$(cat remote_ips)

# Step 1) Create "hduser_pw" password file on each host
for x in $remote_ips; do
    sshpass -p$hduser_pw ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@$x "echo $hduser_pw > hduser_pw; chmod 600 hduser_pw"
done
```

Can you spot the security problem? The `echo $hduser_pw` will be saved in the shell history, and may also be visible in `ps` printings. It's better to avoid it. Instead of this:

> ```
> ssh server "echo $hduser_pw > hduser_pw; chmod 600 hduser_pw"
> ```

You can do like this:

```
ssh server "cat > hduser_pw; chmod 600 hduser_pw" < hduser_pw
```

That's a bit hacky and may be confusing.
A simpler option is to `scp` and then `ssh` (for the `chmod`):

```
scp hduser_pw server:
ssh server "chmod 600 hduser_pw"
```

Other simplifications:

- Instead of `echo -e 'y' | ...` you can simplify to `echo y | ...`
- Instead of the messy Step 4, take a look into `ssh-copy-id` if it's available (usually it is in Linux systems)

Comment: Hi @janos -- thanks so much for your guidance.  I made all of your changes and it works great.  I am attaching my revised script below.

Answer (score 0):

First off UUOC, you really should use a while loop and re-directions instead of CAT.

Use this instead for the following steps which merges all steps into one big while loop.

```
while read ips; do sshpass -p$(<hduser_pw) ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@$ips "echo $(<hduser_pw) > hduser_pw; chmod 600 hduser_pw"; sshpass -p$(<hduser_pw) ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hduser@$ips ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -t rsa -N \"\"";sshpass -p$(<hduser_pw) scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no remote_ips hduser@$ips:;done <remote_ips
```

I'll let you fix Step 4 on your own. GL!

Few pointers.

1. Use while loops when reading through lines
2. ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/somekey to avoid 'echo y | ssh-keygen ...'
3. Use redirect '

Good luck! Perhaps this is best if you use some kind of Configuration Management tools to automate this and more.

Comment: Thanks, @likewhoa - I will take a crack at rewriting it with redirections instead of CAT to avoid UUOC.  Philosophical change!  Much appreciated...